# Which JavaScript framework is best for this website idea?

Tags: web-apps, web-development, react, angular, vue.js

Thus far I have only worked with jQuery and I think it's about time I learned a newer framework.

I am planning to make a daily planner / do list / calendar as a desktop browser application. Which framework would be best for this between React, Angular and Vue?

Comment: Well, all the 3 these three are not a programming language but they known as frameworks. They are being used to make the UI/UX and they use JavaScript. I assume that you have adequate knowledge of JS. I would suggest you try each of them and find the one that suits you. If I understood correctly, angular is more MVC based.

Answer (score 1):

great question indeed. This is just my two cents, but if possible, try to learn some PHP. This language can be a bit complex but its infrastructure is amazing. There are all sorts of utilities and tools already built for things like calendar, daily planning, and to-do lists. This is why I use WordPress for my blog. It is built via PHP and the assortment of tools and resources ready to go is unparalleled. Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with React. It is widely used nowadays and there all lot of resources and videos from which you can benefit to learn it. It was developed by Facebook, and nowadays it is used by most of the big companies and thousands of developers as well. There are also lots of libraries available to extend its capabilities. I suggest you also to learn Node.js & Express for the backend, really flexible and easy to learn and implement. Last but not least, I would recommend you to take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QBYrKhqgFI) video.

I hope my answer helps you.